# Notepad++ perform multiple actions to multiple files at once

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, macros

I have like 20 subtitle files where I do these actions one by one:

- Encoding > Character Sets > Central European > Windows 12-50
  (ctrl+shift+E shortcut)
- Encoding > Convert to UTF-8-BOM (cltr+shift+w shortcut)
- And a macro for search & replace some letters:

```
<Macro name="replacer" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="13">
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="(&#x00E2;)|(&#x015F;)|(&#x015E;)|(&#x0103;)|(&#x0162;)|(&#x00CE;)|(&#x00EE;)|(&#x0163;)|(&#x00C2;)|(&#x0102;)|(&#x021B;)|(&#x0219;)|(&#x0218;)|(&#x021A;)" />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="(?1a)(?2s)(?3S)(?4a)(?5T)(?6I)(?7i)(?8t)(?9A)(?10A)(?11t)(?12s)(?13S)(?14T)" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="770" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
        </Macro>
```

How could I perform those 3 actions to multiple files at once? Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: Honestly, you should be able to create a Notepad++ macro that performs all those operations on an open file, then switch tabs, and repeat using Macro > Run a Macro Multiple Times... for the remaining number of files you have open in Notepad++.  While this isn't *at once*, it does apply the same macro logic across multiple open files *sequentially*.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing Romanian language into Windows 10, so ANSI files could be read without problems in notepad++ without changing character sets.
I just made a new macro that search for

```
(â)|(ş)|(Ş)|(ă)|(Ţ)|(Î)|(î)|(ţ)|(Â)|(Ă)|(ț)|(ș)|(Ș)|(Ț)|(Þ)|(þ)|(ã)|(ª)|(º)|(Ã)|(Ю)|(Г)|(г)|(ю)|(в)|(є)|(О)|(о)|(Є)|(Ă£)|(Ă®)|(ĂŽ)|(Ă¾)|(Ă¢)|(Âş)|(ÂŞ)
```

and replace with

```
(?1a)(?2s)(?3S)(?4a)(?5T)(?6I)(?7i)(?8t)(?9A)(?10A)(?11t)(?12s)(?13S)(?14T)(?15T)(?16t)(?17a)(?18S)(?19s)(?20A)(?21T)(?22A)(?23a)(?24t)(?25a)(?26s)(?27I)(?28i)(?29S)(?30a)(?31i)(?32I)(?33t)(?34a)(?35s)(?36S)
```

and hits replace all opened documents, doing that after I open all the subtitle files that I want "fixed", then I "save all". The best thig I could come up, hope helps someone else too.